# First database creation in android

Tags: android

I have an app and I didn't use database up the present.Now I will update my app and this app contains a database.I am curious about this.Which method will call on updated phones in database `onCreate` or `onUpgrade` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first time if db don't exist, onCreate() method will run.

if db exist and your current db version is higher than installed version, onUpgrade() will run and you should check version in onUpgrade method and do what you want.

here is an example of dbHandler.java class.

```
    package com.app.util;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Milad
 */
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    private static final String DB_NAME = "YourDbName";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;


    public DBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        //Create firstTable
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE TEST ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name TEXT);");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (oldVersion >2) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEST");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I want to protect datas in a table on upgrade what should i do ?

Comment: @Okan you should just do new changes in onUpgrade just like table changes, add columns and ...
if your db not changed you dont need to update db version and old db and datas will remain without any changes.

Comment: can you give an example for add columns ?

Comment: `@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (oldVersion < 6) {
  db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE TestTable ADD COLUMN ColumnName VARCHAR DEFAULT null");
        }
    }`

Answer (score 1):

When you first create the database `onCreate()` method will be called. If you upgrade the database version then that time `onUpgrade()` method will be called.